# Left and right subscripts in multline environment

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, multline

I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\big_{1}[_{2}(...)_{2}\big]_{1}.
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

The lower suffix works only for right and it does not work for left. Is there anyway so that I can fix this problem.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please always test your code before posting, I fixed it in your previous question but you have just done the same again, your example just produced ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \documentclass{12 pt}{   It should be `[12pt]` in square brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude solution is to use `.` as a dummy delimiter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}         
\big._{1}[_{2}(...)_{2}\big]_{1}. 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

The `\prescript` command from the [mathtools package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) is a more satisfactory approach.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}  
\prescript{}{1}{[_{2}(...)_{2}\big]_{1}}.
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: using `.` won't result in delimiters of matching size, which is what i think is wanted.  so, even using `\prescript` (a good idea), `\big` should most likely be inserted before `[`.  (i can't test this; on the road.)